# generating dynamic graphs from tableau onto an android app

Tags: android

Im trying to design an android app that will invoke some dynamically generated graphs from the tableau software. for example, the event can be a button click or selecting from a drop down...when this is done, another page should open with the graphs generated. is there an android developer api for tableau community edition or the desktop edition? or is it something that can be achieved through the server edition of tableau? i am a student and i am looking for something that is free (isnt tableau server edition a paid service?)
any help is appreciated...thanks!

Comment: Tableau java or android api's are not availble. But javascript api's are available. You can implement your app on some hybrid platform like phonegap and utilise the Javascript api for integration.

Comment: Thanks Alok. But now i have decided to just import image files which will have the static graphs, into the app. so the fnuctionality should be that when i choose an option from a drop down and click a button to 'get' the image, there should be another screen with the image.

Comment: Can I get an idea of how to do this? most of the examples i get on the internet talk about how to have an image as the app icon and things like that...

Comment: From where will you be importing images? From web server or assets? Please provide these details.

Answer (score 0):

- Publish your dashboard in tableau public.
- Click on share and copy embed code.
- Create web view in android.
- Design html for mobile view and paste that embed code.